# What i should use: strcpy or pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

```
typedef struct node{
char *name;
//etc...
}N
```

If i had char *string got from stdin and i wanted to pass it to N, i could do easily N->name=string, or it would be bettere to use strcpy?
which is more correct? which is more efficient? why?

Comment: We don't know. Show more context.

Comment: which one would you use?
if "it depends", in what depends?

Comment: @Joshua the result is the same, but what's the difference?

Comment: The result is not the same. It's up to you to describe your use-case, not us to list the possible ones.

Comment: @thesmizzle It comes down to the details of the application. How long does the string need remain accessible? It's like the difference between me saying "the document you need is on my desk" or "here's your own copy of the document". If I'm sure it will stay on my desk as long as you might possibly need to see it, you don't need your own copy. If it might not, you do.

Comment: Note that if you call `strcpy` without allocation enough memory to the `N->name`, a `segmentation fault` will be thrown.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz collected in a linked list and deleted if someone from stdin writes the command to delete it.
p.s. beautiful explanation

Comment: if you've got a linked list then very likely you will use pointers. You will probably either use `strcpy` or directly read into allocated memory.

Comment: @thesmizzle If it is guaranteed to remain valid for as long as any other code might need to see it then a pointer to it is sufficient. If not, then you will need to allocate a separate chunk of memory and copy the string into it.

Comment: If you use `N->name = string;`, you need to make sure that there's a different `string` for each `N`.

Comment: @Barmar And that each `string` lives as long as `N` does.

Comment: The choice probably isn't between pointers and strcpy, it's between pointers and arrays, e.g. `char name[MAXSIZE];`

Comment: By doing `N->name=string` you're assigning the pointer, so every change to `string` will also change `N->name`, so if you plan to process multiple values then it's better to use `strdup` which allocate new memory for N->name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a buffer to read your input from stdin. But if you don't make a copy, your string will be lost at the next read iteration. If you are going to allocate memory, and if you don't know the size of the string you receive, you  should use a function like [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) instead of strcpy.

```
node->name = strdup(string_to_copy);
if (node->name == NULL)
     printf("My allocation has failed!\n");
```

The allocated memory will have to be freed afterward. If the allocation fails, you will have a message (you should always check the success of your memory allocation).

If you don't want to allocate memory and if you know that the size of your input will never be higher than say, 100, you could get away with something like this:

```
typedef struct node{
char name[100];
//etc...
}N
```

In that case you could use the following. Note that strcpy is a dangerous function that should be used with extra-care:

```
strncpy(node->name, buffer, 100);
strcpy(node->name, buffer);
```

EDIT:

Here is a way to free your memory properly:

```
if (node->name != NULL)
{
   free(node->name);
   node->name = NULL;
}
```

This construction will free your memory and helps preventing double-free.

Comment: how would you free the memory after the strdup?

Comment: Added an edit with how to free your memory. With a way to avoid double-free if you are going to iterate a lot.

Comment: It's never necessary to check for NULL before calling `free()` because `free()` is defined as doing nothing if the argument is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Answering "the result is the same, but what's the difference?" (from comment)

Starting from:

```
N *node = malloc(sizeof(N));
char input_from_stdin[80];
```

If we do

```
strcpy(node->name, input_from_stdin);
```

we invoke undefined behavior, but it might appear to work.

If we do

```
node->name = input_from_stdin;
```

than `node->name` only contains its expected value until `input_from_stdin` is reused, which is typically when the next line is read form input.

If we do

```
node->name = malloc(strlen(input_from_stdin) + 1);
strcpy(node->name, input_from_stdin);
```

we make a copy of the input that lives until we free it; but we must remember to free `node->name` before freeing `node`.

We can also do

```
typedef struct node{
    char name[MAXSIZE];
    //etc...
 }N;
```

and then expect

```
strncpy(node->name, input_from_stdin, MAXSIZE-1)[MAXSIZE-1] = 0;
```

to work.

Some poeple do

```
strncpy(node->name, input_from_stdin, MAXSIZE);
```

which is valid but getting it back out again is touchier. This is rarely seen out of fixed-width records on disk now. We don't like `MAXSIZE` much anymore and prefer everything stretchy.

Comment: *'We don't like MAXSIZE much anymore'* – unless on micro controllers...